# Android studio how to get sqlite table name from user in java

Tags: java, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

I want to get a name with edittext from user, and set this name as new table name in SQLite.
Like

`database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS variable_name (...)")`

Comment: Make an attempt first and return with the code you tried so that people can help with issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Names of elements, such as table names, column names, trigger names, index names etc cannot be passed as variables within SQL to SQLite for SQLite to resolve. You would have to resolve the variable name when building the SQL statement.

e.g.

```
database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + variable_name + " (...)");
```